# How to deploy many ECS services using one instance and one load balancer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, amazon-elb

I'm new to AWS and I am trying to gauge what migrating our existing applications into AWS would look like. I'm trying to host multiple apps as Services under a single ECS cluster, and use one Application Load Balancer with hostname rules to route requests to the correct container.

I was originally thinking I could give each service its own Target Group, but I ran into the `RESOURCE:ENI` error, which from what I can tell means that I can't just attach as many Target Groups as I want to the same cluster.

I don't want to create a separate cluster for each app, or use separate load balancers for them because these apps are very small and receive little to no traffic so it just wouldn't make sense. Even the minimum of 0.25 vCPU/0.5 GB that Fargate has is overkill for these apps.

What's the best way to host many apps under one ECS cluster and one Load Balancer? Is it best to create my own reverse-proxy server to do the routing to different apps?

Comment: `I was originally thinking I could give each service its own Target Group, but I ran into the RESOURCE:ENI error` - Are you creating everything from the web console? Did you manually create the target groups or did you let the ECS service create them for you? Also, which [target type](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/load-balancer-target-groups.html#target-type) your target group had?

Comment: @ruohola I don't want the target groups being created automatically because I want to manage this with Terraform eventually. I want them managed as separate objects so I created the service using the CLI and set it to an existing Target Group. Everything besides the Service was configured in the web console. I've tried with both IP and Instance types.

Comment: The target group was IP type and empty when I created the service using CLI. That worked, but when I tried doing the same with another target group and another service, I got `RESOURCE:ENI`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are likely using `awsvpc` [network mode](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html#network_mode) for the task definitions. You could change it to the (default) `bridge` mode instead. Your services don't seem to be ones that would need the added network performance boost of using the native EC2 networking stack.

The target groups' target types should be `instance` as per my understanding.